# Is it allowed to extend an existing question?

Tags: discussion

Some time, i see that some of the questioner extend their questions after getting the answer of the previous question. Yes, Some time questioner may ask relevant info. But some time the extend portion it self looks like a new question.

So, my question is it legal to do so? And if it is not, then how to report on it?

Comment: A very good question, I've seen this often. Personally, if I have answered a question, and the OP asks a further question, I'm willing to further answer if a) my original answer was incomplete, b) the answer is a yes/no or c) the original question was incomplete and the right answer would change. I might not get back to the questioner in c) if the initial question has changed significantly and my answer can't be fixed with a relatively simple fix. In any case I like Mohamed El-Qassas's approach of accepting the answering which answers the initial question. It's the fairest approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends based on the type of extension

- If the extension purpose is adding more information to make the question more clear, So in this case, it would be acceptable!
- Otherwise, the OP should close the current question by accepting the correct answer, then open a new thread for his new question even it related to the main question!

**So in such cases,** you should flag this behavior and select **`in need of moderator intervention`** and please mention your concern to can help!

[image]